# Crashlytics and runZonedGuarded

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, crashlytics

I couldn't understand the crashlytics documentation  for runZonedGuarded usage

So do I need it or not?

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/usage/#zoned-errors

Comment: Here is an example https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/firebase_crashlytics/example you can follow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**June 2023 Answer**:

No, you don't need `runZonedGuarded` for Crashlytics anymore.

Using `runZonedGuarded` for Crashlytics is deprecated. You can see that in this commit where all references to `runZonedGuarded` were replaced:

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/commit/8a0caa05d5abf6fef5bf0e654654dcd0b6ec874a

Also note that the current official documentation doesn't mention `runZonedGuarded` anymore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=flutter

The recommended way is this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);
    };
    // Pass all uncaught asynchronous errors that aren't handled by the Flutter framework to Crashlytics
    PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
      return true;
    };
    runApp(MyApp());

}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Because not all errors can be caught by Flutter framework. For example, an exception happens inside the `onPressed` handler of a button:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    throw Error();
  }
  ...
)
```

To catch such errors, we can use `runZonedGuarded`.

More info:

1. [Handling errors in Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/errors)
2. [Customize your Firebase Crashlytics crash reports - Zoned errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=flutter#zoned-errors)